# Javascript issue in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot get any of my javascript to work on bootstrap here's the call:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
```

And this is the thing i'm trying to get to work

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="dropdown all-camera-dropdown">
           <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            All Cameras
               <b class="caret"></b>
           </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li data-filter-camera-type="all"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">All Cameras</a></li>
            <li data-filter-camera-type="Alpha"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Alpha</a></li>
            <li data-filter-camera-type="Zed"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Zed</a></li>
            <li data-filter-camera-type="Bravo"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#">Bravo</a></li>

     </ul>
</li></ul>
```

Comment: What is it doing and what do you want it to do exactly? Also, why are you loading the bootstrap library twice? You only need to do it once. Either include `bootstrap.js` or `bootstrap.min.js`.

Comment: It doesn't seems that you have had a link to [jquery](http://jquery.com/), bootstrap plugins are build on it, also it's redundant to have minified and the normal version. Remove one of them

Comment: More than redundant, loading the plugins twice has been known to cause errors. You **must** load it only once. Check the answers for the primary reason of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the `jquery` library before bootstraps. It relies on it.

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`